# Recursion is skipping values

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to assign/place a set of numbers **randomly** within a new array as a pair: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` should equal `[[1,1],[8,8],[3,3],[7,7],[2,2],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6]]`

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

let arrayToBeFilled = [];

function assign(num) {

 let randomNumber =  Number(Math.floor((Math.random() * 8)));

  if(arrayToBeFilled[randomNumber] == null ) {

    arrayToBeFilled[randomNumber] = [num, num] ;

  } else if (arrayToBeFilled[randomNumber] == Array) {

   return  assign(num);

  } else {

    console.log('Trying a new number');

  }
}

  for (num in numbers) {

    assign(Number(num));

  }

 console.log(arrayToBeFilled);  
 return arrayToBeFilled;
```

Returns the array but with values missing where the recursion should have filled the array (what I'm expecting at least). See <1 empty item>.

```
Trying a new number
Trying a new number
Trying a new number
[ [ 0, 0 ], [ 7, 7 ], [ 5, 5 ], <1 empty item>, [ 2, 2 ], [ 1, 1 ] ]
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening??

Comment: `for (num in numbers) {` iterates over *keys*, not *values* (they are zero based)

Comment: what are you trying to do with this code?

Answer (score 1):

I made some edits to your code:

```js
/* prefer functions instead of global variables */
function main() {
  let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  let arrayToBeFilled = [];

  for (num of numbers) { /* Use 'for...of' syntax for array iteration */
    assign(Number(num), arrayToBeFilled);
  }

  return arrayToBeFilled
}

function assign(num, arr) {
  const randomNumber = Number(Math.floor((Math.random() * 8)));
  if (arr[randomNumber] == null) {
    arr[randomNumber] = [num, num];
  } else if (Array.isArray(arr[randomNumber])) { /* Proper way to check if element is an Array type */
    return assign(num, arr);
  } else {
    return []
  }
}

console.log(main());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take. The beauty of this is of course the abstraction in form of the shuffle function which works on all arrays, and can be put away into a utility sub file.

```
function shuffle(a) {
    // you can replace this with "let n = a" if you don't care about  
    // the incoming array being altered
    let n = [...a]; 
    for (let i = n.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [n[i], n[j]] = [n[j], n[i]];
    }
    return n;
}

let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
console.log( shuffle( numbers ).map( n => [n,n] ) );
```

Comment: The right way to do it, a solid Fisher-Yates implementation for the shuffle and then do the transform from n to [n,n] afterwards.

Comment: `n` could (should) still be `const` - ie, it will always point to the same array reference

Answer (score 0):

**NON-REPEATING random numbers** (https://jsfiddle.net/th3vecmg/2/)

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let arrayToBeFilled = [];

function assign(numbers, i, size) {

  if (i < size) {
    assign(numbers, ++i, size);
  }

  var randomNumber = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
  arrayToBeFilled.push([randomNumber, randomNumber]);
  numbers.splice(numbers.indexOf(randomNumber), 1);
}

assign(numbers, 0, numbers.length - 1)

console.log(arrayToBeFilled);
```

**REPEATING random numbers** (https://jsfiddle.net/th3vecmg/3/)

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let arrayToBeFilled = [];

function assign(numbers, i) {
  let randomNumber = Number(Math.floor((Math.random() * 8)));
  arrayToBeFilled[i] = [randomNumber, randomNumber];

  if (i < numbers.length - 1) {
    assign(numbers, ++i);
  }
}

assign(numbers, 0)
console.log(arrayToBeFilled);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create function that will randomize elements and return array of the nth length for each element using `while` loop.

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

function randomize(data, n) {
  const result = [];
  data = data.slice();

  while (data.length) {
    const pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
    const el = data.splice(pos, 1).pop();
    result.push(Array.from(Array(n), () => el));
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(randomize(numbers, 2))
console.log(randomize(numbers, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function assign(num) {

 let randomNumber =  Number(Math.floor((Math.random() * 8)));

  if(arrayToBeFilled[randomNumber] == null ) {

    arrayToBeFilled[randomNumber] = [num + 1, num + 1] ;

  } else {

   assign(num);

  }
}
```

You had an else in the code which was skipping one place in the array to be filled

Comment: Though unlikely, this could potentially run forever and blow up the stack.

Comment: I agree. A better solution can be assigning the random numbers to the indices in linear order, instead of assigning the index to the random place in the array.

Comment: I think your right, the else statement was keeping a value of <empty> in the array which was then skipping to the else as there was no catch for it. By adding a ` OR true ` to the else if block, it worked: (arrayToBeFilled[randomNumber] == Number || true)

Comment: You do not need `else if`. As suggested in your comment, `arrayToBeFilled[randomNumber] == Number` is always going to be `false` and `|| true` is always going to be `true`. Hence, there is no need for `else if`. Just use an `else`. Please accept my answer as the solution if this makes sense.